# MySQL - need help in improving query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, transaction-isolation

Original question was based on where best to set tx isolation to READ UNCOMMITTED but after some advise it would seem that my initial thoughts on that as a possible solution was incorrect.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `tblgpslog` (
    `GPSLogID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DTSaved` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PrimaryAssetID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SecondaryAssetID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ThirdAssetID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `JourneyType` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'B',
    `DateStamp` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Status` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Location` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `Latitude` DECIMAL(11,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Longitude` DECIMAL(11,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `GPSFix` CHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Speed` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Heading` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LifeOdometer` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Extra` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BatteryLevel` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT '--',
    `Ignition` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `Radius` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `GSMLatitude` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    `GSMLongitude` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`GPSLogID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `GPSLogID` (`GPSLogID`),
    INDEX `SecondaryUnitID` (`SecondaryAssetID`),
    INDEX `ThirdUnitID` (`ThirdAssetID`),
    INDEX `DateStamp` (`DateStamp`),
    INDEX `PrimaryUnitIDDateStamp` (`PrimaryAssetID`, `DateStamp`, `Status`),
    INDEX `Location` (`Location`),
    INDEX `DTSaved` (`DTSaved`),
    INDEX `PrimaryAssetID` (`PrimaryAssetID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=153076364
;
```

The original query is as follows

```
SELECT L.GPSLogID, L.DateStamp, L.Status, Location, Latitude, Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, BatteryLevel, Ignition, L.Extra 
FROM tblGPSLog L 
WHERE PrimaryAssetID = 183 AND L.GPSLogID > 147694199
ORDER BY DateStamp ASC 
LIMIT 100;

"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","SIMPLE","L","index_merge","PRIMARY,GPSLogID,PrimaryUnitIDDateStamp,PrimaryAssetID","PrimaryAssetID,PRIMARY","9,8",\N,"96","Using intersect(PrimaryAssetID,PRIMARY); Using where; Using filesort"
```

This gave issues a few months ago and after a bit of investigation I changed the query to below, but that is now acting very similar.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT GPSLogID, DateStamp, tmpA.Status, Location, Latitude, Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, BatteryLevel, Ignition, tmpA.Extra, 
PrimaryAssetID FROM (SELECT L.GPSLogID, L.DateStamp, L.Status, Location, Latitude, Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, 
BatteryLevel, Ignition, L.Extra, PrimaryAssetID 
FROM tblGPSLog L 
WHERE L.GPSLogID > 147694199) AS tmpA 
WHERE PrimaryAssetID = 183 
ORDER BY DateStamp ASC;

"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","PRIMARY","<derived2>","ALL",\N,\N,\N,\N,"5380842","Using where; Using filesort"
"2","DERIVED","L","range","PRIMARY,GPSLogID","PRIMARY","8",\N,"8579290","Using where"
```

Thanks for any advise.

Jim

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: If practical, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ..` for the one where it says "Using intersect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statements

> its rare that an SELECT would hit the table while INSERT is happening and even if it does, it wouldn't cause any great issues.
>   DELETE statements are scheduled once a week only at off peak hours,

equate to "Changing the isolation mode won't help much."

I recommend setting `long_query_time=1` and turning on the slowlog.  Later, look through the slowlog with `pt-query-digest` to find the few "worst" queries.  Then let's discuss improving them.

**More**

```
INDEX `PrimaryUnitIDDateStamp` (`PrimaryAssetID`, `DateStamp`,
INDEX `PrimaryAssetID`         (`PrimaryAssetID`)
```

The first of those takes care of the second, so the second is unnecessary.

```
PRIMARY KEY             (`GPSLogID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `GPSLogID` (`GPSLogID`),
```

A PK is a UNIQUE key, so chuck the second of those.  That extra *unique* index slows down inserts and wastes disk space.

In this, I see no reason to have a query and subquery:

```
SELECT  GPSLogID, DateStamp, tmpA.Status, Location, Latitude,
        Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, BatteryLevel,
        Ignition, tmpA.Extra, PrimaryAssetID
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  L.GPSLogID, L.DateStamp, L.Status, Location, Latitude,
                  Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, BatteryLevel,
                  Ignition, L.Extra, PrimaryAssetID
            FROM  tblGPSLog L
            WHERE  L.GPSLogID > 147694199
        ) AS tmpA
    WHERE  PrimaryAssetID = 183
    ORDER BY  DateStamp ASC;
```

A pair of `DECIMAL(11,8)` adds up to 12 bytes, and is overkill for lat&lng.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) for smaller alternatives.

The table has been growing in size, correct?  And, after it got so big, performance took a nose dive?  Shrinking datatypes to shrink the table is one approach, albeit a temporary fix.

`Using intersect(PrimaryAssetID,PRIMARY)` -- Almost always, it is better to build a composite index than to use "Index merge intersect".

Although

```
INDEX `PrimaryAssetID`         (`PrimaryAssetID`)
```

*should* have been equivalent to

```
INDEX `PrimaryAssetID`         (`PrimaryAssetID`, GPSLogID)
```

something is preventing it.  Suggest you add this 2-column composite index.  Perhaps a large percentage of rows have `PrimaryAssetID = 183`??  If convenient, please do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblgpslog WHERE PrimaryAssetID = 183`

Will you be purging 'old' data from this log?  If so, the optimal way involves `PARTITIONing`; see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: I know the query that is impacting the performance. It has been operating perfectly for years and recently it's been slowing down to being unusable.    The where clause is based on two separate indexes, a primary key called LogID and an index called PrimaryAssetID.  Problem is, if the LogID is "old" - say it was created a month ago - the query is slow, if the key was created in the last week, it's fast (under a second).  I'm not even sure where to start to investigate this.

Comment: Aha!  MySQL does not like using two separate indexes, and some things have changed in the Optimizer.  We really need to see the things (show, explain, etc) that Bill asked for.  And preferably the `EXPLAIN` from both the old system and the new.  If you are/were getting "Index merge intersect", there is very likely to be a simple solution.  Need details.

Comment: Thanks Rick, let me put that information together.  One point I should clear up, when I stated SELECT would hit the table while INSERT is happening, I should state that INSERTS and UPDATE are constantly happening.  If someone runs a report (using SELECT), its unlikely that the particular records in question would be updated at that time.

Comment: @JimBuckleyBarret - `SELECT` one row, with a suitable index?  Or `SELECT` a lot of rows (as for a "report")?

Comment: Might be one row or hundreds, depends on what parameters the user select from the web page.

Comment: The original SQL, that started to give issues was "EXPLAIN SELECT ...
FROM tblGPSLog L 
WHERE PrimaryAssetID = 183 AND L.GPSLogID > 147694199
ORDER BY DateStamp ASC 
LIMIT 100;"  The EXPLAIN result "id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","SIMPLE","L","index_merge","PRIMARY,GPSLogID,PrimaryUnitIDDateStamp,PrimaryAssetID","PrimaryAssetID,PRIMARY","9,8",\N,"96","Using intersect(PrimaryAssetID,PRIMARY); Using where; Using filesort"

Comment: I updated that to the following query and it did improve performance for a few months.  EXPLAIN SELECT GPSLogID, DateStamp, tmpA.Status, Location, Latitude, Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, BatteryLevel, Ignition, tmpA.Extra, 
PrimaryAssetID FROM (SELECT L.GPSLogID, L.DateStamp, L.Status, Location, Latitude, Longitude, GPSFix, Speed, Heading, LifeOdometer, 
BatteryLevel, Ignition, L.Extra, PrimaryAssetID 
FROM tblGPSLog L 
WHERE L.GPSLogID > 147694199) AS tmpA 
WHERE PrimaryAssetID = 183 
ORDER BY DateStamp ASC;

Comment: EXPLAIN results - "id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","PRIMARY","<derived2>","ALL",\N,\N,\N,\N,"5380842","Using where; Using filesort"
"2","DERIVED","L","range","PRIMARY,GPSLogID","PRIMARY","8",\N,"8579290","Using where"

Comment: @JimBuckleyBarret - I added some more stuff.

Comment: apologies in the delay getting back to you.  I've eventually got the 88GB database restored onto my laptop and completed the changed you suggested around the indexes.  There is certainly a massive improvement.  I'm going to continue with some more testing and then upgrade the production server.  Really appreciate all the help and again apologies for the delay in replying.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe setting tx isolation to READ UNCOMMITTED, will stop the SELECT from locking the table.

Why would you believe that READ UNCOMMITTED will accomplish that?

SELECT is already non-locking by default in all isolation levels except for SERIALIZABLE.

That is, SELECT is always non-locking unless you use `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE` / `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. When using SERIALIZABLE isolation level, SELECT is implicitly converted to a locking SELECT `FOR SHARE`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

I strongly recommend to **never** use READ UNCOMMITTED. This is not a good idea, because your transaction can read *uncommitted* work by other transactions, which means you can read inconsistent data (partially completed transactions), and phantom data (changes from transactions that are eventually rolled back). There is no advantage to doing this, and a potential for queries returning wrong results.

What makes you think locking is the cause of your performance problem? Have you observed an increase in lock time in the slow query log?

It's more common for performance problems to be caused by poor query optimization or not enough system resource.

If your database has become slower after 8+ years, I would guess that the database has grown until the active data set no longer fits in RAM.

---

Re your comment:

> Is there a tool or way to investigate this further? I know the query that causing the issue, just can't determine why

There are many tools and ways to investigate. There are books on this subject like [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do), and whole companies devoted to creating performance monitoring tools, like [Percona](http://percona.com) and [VividCortex](http://vividcortex.com).

I can't guess at a suggestion without knowing more specific details. If you want more help, can you please edit your original question above and add:

- The SQL query that is having trouble.
- The output of `EXPLAIN <query>` for the query that's having trouble.
- The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table referenced by the query. You can run this statement in the MySQL client.

That's for starters.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a valid use for a dirty read:  `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE...` in a situation where an approximate count is good enough?

Comment: As far as I know, read uncommitted has no benefit over read committed for query performance or locking behavior.

Comment: Hi Bill, I must have misunderstood other posts, I thought SELECT did complete row locks by default and READ UNCOMMITTED would prevent this, allowing other SELECT, INSERTS and the are DELETE to execute as normal.  I am seeing performance issues especially with one query type that I have changed but only for it to return again as an issue.  That particular query can run for a less than a second and then again for 5+ minutes.  The only difference would be the WHERE clause but the key is indexed so in theory, I would have thought that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: "If your database has become slower after 8+ years, I would guess that the database has grown until the active data set no longer fits in RAM."  The database is now aroudn 100GB in size, but because we only hold X months of data it hasn't grown beyond this, so for the most part it has remained the same size for a while now as far as I can tell.

Comment: "It's more common for performance problems to be caused by poor query optimization or not enough system resource to be caused by query performance." - Is there a tool or way to investigate this further?  I know the query that causing the issue, just can't determine why

Comment: Wow, I screwed up that sentence while editing. Sorry about that. I'll add some content to my answer.